# Adding error handling to check for a condition before execution

Tags: excel

Hello and than you all for your time, I have the code below, there's a RUN button on my spreadsheet that executes the SUB RUN ALL macro. The first call function, deletes all the tabs and imports a sheet from a file on my desktop named "MyFiles".

What I want is to first check for the presence of that file, before doing anything else, and if not there, display a short message and exit the sub and not run anything else.

Should I incorporate something in the IMPORT DATA sub? or make a new sub to run first and check for that file and exit if not present?

Thanking you all in advance.

```
Sub Run_All()

Call Import_Data
Call Cut_Series2
Call Cut_Series5
Call Cut_Series6
Call Cut_Series8
Call Cut_SeriesH
Call Cut_Trailers
Call Cut_PPE
Call Cut_Dewatering
Call Cut_Nicolas
Call Cut_Facilities

End Sub



Sub Import_Data()

Dim x As Workbook
Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
Dim xWs As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

' This part delets all sheets except the summary tab
     For Each xWs In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If xWs.Name <> "Summary" Then
            xWs.Delete
        End If
    Next

' This part will get the raw data from the downloaded file on the desktop
     Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\mohammad.reza\Desktop\MyFiles.xls")
     Set targetWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook

' This part will copy the sheet into this workbook
     With x.Sheets("MyFiles").UsedRange
     ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Range("A1").Resize( _
        .Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value
     End With
     x.Close

' This part will rename the sheet and move it to the end
ActiveSheet.Name = "RAW DATA"
ActiveSheet.Move After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make `Import_Data` into a function then you can return success/failure and exit your man sub if no file was found.

```
Sub Run_All()

    If Not Import_Data() Then Exit Sub
    Cut_Series2
    'etc

End Sub



Function Import_Data() As Boolean
    Const F_PATH As String = "C:\Users\mohammad.reza\Desktop\MyFiles.xls"

    'if no file then exit and return false
    If Dir(F_PATH) = "" Then
        Import_Data = False
        Exit Function
    End If

    'load the file

    Import_Data = True '=success

End Function
```

Comment: This worked like a DREAM, thanks so much Tim. I don't know how to thank you enough.